# kubernetes pod scheduling with resource quotas

Tags: kubernetes, resources

I have read about k8s resource management but things are still not very clear to me.  Lets say we have 2 k8s nodes each with 22 mb memory.
Lets say Pod A has request 10mb and limit 15mb(but lets say actual usage is 5mb). so this pod is scheduled on node 1. So node1 has 22 mb memory, 5 is used by Pod A but another 17mb is available if more memory is needed by Pod A.
Pod B has request 10 and limit 15(basically the same with Pod A). so this pod is scheduled on node 2

So both nodes have 5 mbs of usages out of 22mb. If Pod C has a request 5mb and limit 10mb, will this pod be scheduled on any of the nodes? If yes, what would happen Pod C needs 10m memory and the other pod needs 15mb of memory?

What would happen if Pod C has a request of 13mb and a limit of 15mb? In this case 13(request of pod C) + 10(request of pod A) will be 23(more than 22)?

Does k8s try to make sure that requests of all pods < available memory &&  limits of all pods < available memory ?

Comment: **Assuming** that your node has 22mb of RAM and noone of it is used by other components and you tried to spawn a `Pod` on it that has a **request** of 10MB and then spawn a `Pod` that has a **request** of 15MB, the `Pod` will stay in the `Pending` state as Kubernetes can't guarantee that 15MB of RAM will be available (even if first `Pod` uses no resources). I see that you've reviewed the K8S documentation about it but have you seen the docs about [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/#kube-scheduler)?

Answer (score 2):

Answering question from the post:

> Lets say Pod A has request 10mb and limit 15mb(but lets say actual usage is 5mb). so this pod is scheduled on node 1. So node1 has 22 mb memory, 5 is used by Pod A but another 17mb is available if more memory is needed by Pod A. Pod B has request 10 and limit 15(basically the same with Pod A). so this pod is scheduled on node 2

This is not really a question but I think this part needs some perspective on how `Pods` are scheduled onto the nodes. The component that is responsible for telling Kubernetes where a `Pod` should be scheduled is: `kube-scheduler`. It **could** come to the situation as you say that:

- `Pod A, req:10M, limit: 15M` -> `Node 1, mem: 22MB`
- `Pod B req:10M, limit: 15M` -> `Node 2, mem: 22MB`

Citing the official documentation:

> #### Node selection in kube-scheduler
>
> `kube-scheduler` selects a node for the pod in a 2-step operation:
>
> - Filtering
> - Scoring
>
> The filtering step finds the set of Nodes where it's feasible to schedule the Pod. For example, the PodFitsResources filter checks whether a candidate Node has enough available resource to meet a Pod's specific resource requests. After this step, the node list contains any suitable Nodes; often, there will be more than one. If the list is empty, that Pod isn't (yet) schedulable.
>
> In the scoring step, the scheduler ranks the remaining nodes to choose the most suitable Pod placement. The scheduler assigns a score to each Node that survived filtering, basing this score on the active scoring rules.
>
> **Finally, kube-scheduler assigns the Pod to the Node with the highest ranking.** If there is more than one node with equal scores, kube-scheduler selects one of these at random.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Scheduling eviction: Kube sheduler: Implementation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/#kube-scheduler-implementation)*

---

> So both nodes have 5 mbs of usages out of 22mb. If Pod C has a request 5mb and limit 10mb, will this pod be scheduled on any of the nodes? If yes, what would happen Pod C needs 10m memory and the other pod needs 15mb of memory?

In this particular example I would much more focus on the **request** part rather than the actual usage. Assuming that there is no other factor that will deny the scheduling, `Pod C` should be spawned on one of the nodes (that the `kube-scheduler` chooses). Why is that?:

- `resource.limits` will **not deny** the scheduling of the `Pod` (limit can be higher than memory)
- `resource.requests` will **deny** the scheduling of the `Pod` (request cannot be higher than memory)

I encourage you to check following articles to get more reference:

- *[Sysdig.com: Blog: Kubernetes limits requests](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-limits-requests/)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Blog: Products: Containers Kubernetes: Kubernetes best practices:](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits)*  (this is `GKE` blog but it should give the baseline idea, see the part on: "The lifecycle of a Kubernetes Pod" section)

---

> What would happen if Pod C has a request of 13mb and a limit of 15mb? In this case 13(request of pod C) + 10(request of pod A) will be 23(more than 22)?

In that example the `Pod` **will not** be scheduled as the sum of requests > memory (assuming no `Pod` priority). The `Pod` will be in `Pending` state.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Scheduling eviction: Kube sheduler: What's next](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/#what-s-next)*
- *[Youtube.com: Deep Dive Into the Latest Kubernetes Scheduler Features](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDkE4WNWKUc)*
   - from [CNCF [Cloud Native Computing Foundation]](https://www.cncf.io/) conference